# Missing bytes on IdUDPServer.OnRead event in buffer array - Delphi XE3

Tags: delphi, udp, delphi-xe3, indy10

Can't seem to find anywhere informations about this, but, is TIdUDPServer.OnRead event passing everything that comes in to the AData array or not?

According to WireShark readings, I'm missing 42 bytes of data; While I should be getting 572 bytes of data on each reading, the AData size is always 530, and seems like always the same bytes are missing.

The device that sends data is broadcasting it, and I can get everything I need except for 2 bytes, which seems to be 2 of those that are missing.

Any hints on this one?

Edit:

I should mention that these are the very first 42 bytes; Everything afterwards is received fine;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `OnUDPRead` event passes everything the socket receives from the OS.  UDP operates on messages. Unlike TCP, a UDP read is an all-or-nothing operation, either a whole UDP message is read or an error occurs, there is no in-between.

If you are missing data, then either the OS is not providing it (such as if it belongs to the UDP and/or IP headers), or you are not reading data from the `AData` parameter correctly.  If you think this is not the case, then you need to update your question to show your actual `OnUDPRead` handler code, an example WireShark dump showing the data being captured from the network, and the data that is making it to your `OnUDPRead` handler.

**Update**: The OS does not provide access to the packet headers (unless you are using a RAW socket, which `TIdUDPServer` does not use, but that is a whole other topic of discussion). The `AData` parameter of the `OnUDPRead` event provides only the **application data** portion of a packet, as that is what the OS provides. You cannot access the packet headers.

That being said, you can get the packet's source IP:Port, at least, via the `ABinding.PeerIP` and `ABinding.PeerPort` properties of the `OnUDPRead` event. However, there is no way to retrieve the other packet header values (nor should you ever need them in most situations), unless you sniff the network yourself, such as with a pcap library.

Comment: I did know that it gets whatever the OS forwards on, but didn't know that in only receives whole packet or nothing..
And yes, these 42 bytes are the header data, carrying source's MAC, IP address, protocol info, packet length, etc...  But why aren't they passed on then anyway...?

Comment: Thanks for explanation and clearance on this one. Did not know that the header is unreachable. I knew about PeerIP and PeerPort, but I need the rest as well...
I will check out the pcap library to see if I can get around by sniffing the network...

Comment: Why do you need the other values, though?  They are not typically used by most applications, and have no real benefit in socket programming. You can't send packets to a MAC, only to an IP. And you know the protocol (UDP) by virtue of the type of socket you are working with. So what are you trying to accomplish exactly?

Comment: I'd need to know the first 6 bytes, to determine whether the packet received was broadcasted or sent specifically to the receiving address. I'd also like to get MAC address to validate and confirm the source's credibility. The vital thing though is the port to where the data are being sent. With PeerPort I get the sending port, but I can't determine destination port always...
The need comes from the fact that I'm receiving broadcasted data from several sources, and I'd like to tell my AtMega based hardware what port does it need to listen to for receiving that broadcastings...

Comment: Each source sends to different (mostly random) port, and I get all of the packets to my app, microprocessor, however, has strict port where it listens, so I need to manually change that from my app by sending a command; For now, all of the trafic comes to my app, and is then forwarded to the microprocessor's interface; I'd like to bypass that in order to decrease traffic going through the PC...

Comment: You should not care if the packet was broadcasted or not. It targeted your listening port one way or the other. The OS would not give the packet to you if it did not match your socket criteria. And you know the destination port, because you are the one who opened it in the first place. You ALWAYS know the port that your socket is listening on. As for validating sender MACs, those can be spoofed very easily, so don't even bother trying. Validate the content of the packet's payload instead. If you need to validate the sender, then you need to have the sender authenticate with you beforehand.

Comment: You can't have a socket listening on multiple ports.  It can be listening on multiple local IPs, but not multiple ports.  The only way to do that is to create a separate socket for each port you want to listen on. And given that, you ALWAYS know which port received a packet (the `ABinding.IP` and `ABinding.Port` properties tell you the receiving IP:Port, whereas the `ABinding.PeerIP` and `ABinding.PeerPort` properties tell you the sending IP:Port).

Comment: You are making things much harder than they need to be.  Trust the OS to do the filtering for you, that is its job.  You just focus on the data you are receiving AFTER the OS has decided whether a packet belongs to your socket or not.

Comment: That is correct! I was completely missing the part with only one port being active at a time...  I'm changing them every 500 ms using timer, so that I can I can get all of the packets...  Your suggestion of using multiple sockets is smart one, but I am kind of avoiding that as I've experienced a lot of issues with "cannot bind. Socket already in use" in the past when using more than one server using the same local IP...

Comment: I might just do as you suggested, and then use the UDPServerX identification to tell which received what I need..
As for the MACs -> I'm not worried about spoofed MAC addresses and packets; The devices that are sending data have all hardcoded MAC addresses, and since these are all broadcasted packets, and since IP's are DHCP assigned, it would be good to somehow validate the data has come from expected source...

Comment: You will not be able to receive and validate MACs with a socket API. That information is only used by the network layer, not the application layer. But if you really want to check if a packet was sent to a broadcast IP or a specific IP, you can use `recvmsg()` (`WSARecvMsg()` on Windows), which provides that kind of info, such as the destination IP address. Indy has a `TIdStack.ReceiveMsg()` method that returns dest IP (amongst other things), but you can't use it with `TIdUDPServer` (as it uses `TIdStack.ReceiveFrom()` instead) without altering Indy's source code.